# package com.example.crystalrangeseekbar does not exist React Native

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio

I'm having the next issue when I build my React Native app on Android Studio:

```
package com.example.crystalrangeseekbar does not exist 
import com.example.crystalrangeseekbar.R;
```

I have seek for a solution to this issue but got nothing, someone now how to fix this?
I have tried to sync gradle file but a message still showing in the top.

[image: GradleSyncFailed]

The build error is on BubbleThumbSeekBar.java

```
package com.crystal.crystalrangeseekbar.widgets;

import android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.animation.OvershootInterpolator;

import com.example.crystalrangeseekbar.R;
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: What does your source tree look like?

Comment: Is your file in a matching directory structure as documented here? https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=topics-java-classes-packages-directories

Comment: Right now I think is an issue with an slider library: https://github.com/jesster2k10/react-native-range-slider